# devenv.com not showing up visual studio 2012 for local user

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

devenv.com not showing up visual studio 2012 for local user. Command prompt recognize devenv.com but do nothing and return to dos prompt. Due to this reason **Merge changes in merge tool** from resolve conflict window is not working.

I checked all below scenarios:

1. local user can execute .com dos commands like edit.com, tree.com - no permission issues with executing .com files
2. path is properly given to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE and command prompt recognize the devenv.com
3. devenv.exe works fine for local user and shows up vs2012 ide
4. gave fullcontrol to devenv.com for the local user, still not working
5. devenv.com works fine when run Command prompt as administrator

Please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we installed [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f)  and the problem vanished. Now I am able to run devenv.com from local user command prompt.